# How to get the width and the height of a label after adding wrapped long text into it?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm currently working on my chat app project. My approach is I first put the text in a label and then put the label in a panel. Apparently, when the text is too long that it cannot fit within the panel width, the text will get wrapped.

```
void TextBubble(string message, string side, string time)
{
    string logRole = null;
    if (CreateRoomButtonState)
    {
        if (side == "right")
            logRole = "Server";
        else if (side == "left")
            logRole = "Client";
    }
    else if (JoinRoomButtonState)
    {
        if (side == "right")
            logRole = "Client";
        else if (side == "left")
            logRole = "Server";
    }
    Messages.Add("[" + time + "] " + logRole + ": " + message);
    int timePaddingY = 0;
    Label textBox = new Label();
    Label timeLabel = new Label();
    timeLabel.Text = time;
    timeLabel.Font = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 5);
    timeLabel.ForeColor = Color.Black;
    timeLabel.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
    int limit = 250;
    textBox.AutoSize = true;
    textBox.MaximumSize = new Size(limit, 0);
    textBox.Text = message;
    Size timeSize = TextRenderer.MeasureText(time, MessageBox.Font);
    textBox.Padding = new Padding(5);
    textBox.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
    timeLabel.Width = timeSize.Width;
    timeLabel.Height = timeSize.Height;
    Console.WriteLine("message: " + message);
    Console.WriteLine("textBox.Size.Width: " + textBox.Size.Width);
    Console.WriteLine("textBox.Size.Height: " + textBox.Size.Height);
    if (side == "right")
    {
        textBox.Location = new Point(MessageField.Size.Width - textBox.Size.Width - 15, MessageField.AutoScrollPosition.Y + CurrentY);
        textBox.BackColor = Color.PaleGreen;
        timeLabel.Location = new Point(MessageField.Size.Width - timeLabel.Width - 15, MessageField.AutoScrollPosition.Y + CurrentY + textBox.Size.Height + timePaddingY);
        timeLabel.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleRight;
    }
    else if (side == "left")
    {
        textBox.Location = new Point(0, MessageField.AutoScrollPosition.Y + CurrentY);
        textBox.BackColor = Color.LightBlue;
        timeLabel.Location = new Point(0, MessageField.AutoScrollPosition.Y + CurrentY + textBox.Size.Height + timePaddingY);
        timeLabel.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
    }
    CurrentY += textBox.Size.Height + TextPadingY + timeLabel.Size.Height + timePaddingY;
    if (CreateRoomButtonState || JoinRoomButtonState)
    {
        MessageField.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => MessageField.Controls.Add(textBox)));
        MessageField.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => MessageField.Controls.Add(timeLabel)));
        MessageField.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => MessageField.AutoScrollPosition = new Point(0, MessageField.VerticalScroll.Maximum)));
    }
}
```

In these two lines:

```
Console.WriteLine("textBox.Size.Width: " + textBox.Size.Width);
Console.WriteLine("textBox.Size.Height: " + textBox.Size.Height);
```

I keep getting the output

> textBox.Size.Width: 100

> textBox.Size.Height: 0

Output console for short text

[image: Output console for short text]

Output console for long text

[image: Output console for long text]

No matter how long the text is in the label. This makes me unable to place the text and time labels properly in the panel. How do I fix this?

Comment: You don't need a Panel as container, you need a FlowLayoutPanel. Use its child Controls' `Margin` and the FLP's `Padding` to fine-tune the Layout.

Comment: BTW, you're trying to get the size of an auto-sizing Control too soon. You have to wait until its layout is complete, i.e., after you have added it to a Container -- Why do you have all those `BeginInvoke()` stuff there? Is this code called from a Thread other than the UI Thread? In that case, you have a bigger problem.

Comment: @Jimi I use `BeginInvoke()` because there are two threads for client and server that are run at some timing period. These stuff don't bring me problems at all. Even if I didn't them, those width and height still didn't give the expected values.

Comment: As mentioned, the `AutoSize` feature is only applied when there's a Layout Context, which means the auto-sizing Control must have a Parent. Before that, the requested Size, Maximum/Minimum Size etc. are only cached. These vales are applied right after you set `[Parent].Control.Add([Auto-Sizing Element])` -- Yes, you have a problem. If these *messages* are received from different Threads, you must invoke a method in the UI Thread, passing the values used to create your Controls **in the UI Thread** -- As also mentioned, use a FlowLayoutPanel, so you don't need to calculate anything.

Comment: Access the Width/Height properties *after* the Controls.Add() call.

Answer (score 0):

Jimi is right about needing the layout context. After carefully reading through your code for what you're trying to achieve, I suggest that a good place to do size adjustments would be in the `ControlAdded` event handler for your `MessageField` panel. By the time this handler is called, the new control has a parent and the context is available. What this code is doing is calculating position based on the last previous visible control before making the new one visible which is one approach to solving your question of "how do I fix this" because this way the sizing is already factored in.

```
public MainForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    // Executes whenever a new textBox or timeLabel is added. 
    MessageField.ControlAdded += (sender, e) =>
    {
        e.Control.MaximumSize = new Size(LIMIT, int.MaxValue);
        var lastVisible =
            MessageField.Controls
            .Cast<Control>()
            .LastOrDefault(control => control.Visible);                
        int spacer = 0;
        if(lastVisible != null)
        {
            switch (e.Control.Name)
            {
                case "textBox": 
                    spacer = 2; 
                    break;
                case "timeLabel":
                    if(lastVisible.Name == "textBox")
                    {
                        var minWidth = Math.Max(lastVisible.Width, e.Control.Width);
                        lastVisible.MinimumSize = e.Control.MinimumSize = new Size(minWidth, 0);
                        if(lastVisible.Tag.ToString() == "right")
                        {
                            lastVisible.Location = new Point(
                                MessageField.Width - lastVisible.Width,
                                lastVisible.Location.Y);
                        }
                    }
                    spacer = 0;  break;
                default: throw new NotImplementedException();    
            }
            switch (e.Control.Tag.ToString())
            {
                case "left": e.Control.Location =
                    e.Control.Location = new Point(
                        0,
                        lastVisible.Location.Y + lastVisible.Height + spacer);
                    break;
                case "right":
                    e.Control.Location = new Point(
                        MessageField.Width - e.Control.Width,
                        lastVisible.Location.Y + lastVisible.Height + spacer);
                    break;
            }
        }
        e.Control.Visible = true;
    };
}
```

I tested this with a minimal version of the `TextBubble` method and it seems to work ok. Thought it might give you some ideas if you still are in need of them.

```
void TextBubble(string message, string side, string time)
{
    Label textBox = new Label()
    {
        Name = nameof(textBox),
        Visible = false,
        BackColor = Color.White,
        Font = new Font("SergioUI", 14),
        Padding = new Padding(2, 2, 2, 2),
        AutoSize = true,
        Text = message,
        BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle, // To see what we're doing
        Tag = side,
    };
    MessageField.Controls.Add(textBox);

    Label timeLabel = new Label
    {
        Name = nameof(timeLabel),
        Visible = false,
        BackColor = Color.Transparent,
        Font = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 5),
        Padding = new Padding(2, 2, 2, 2),
        AutoSize = true,
        Text = time,
        BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle,  // To see what we're doing
        Width = textBox.Width,
        Location = new Point(textBox.Location.X, textBox.Location.Y + textBox.Height),
        Tag = side,
    };
    MessageField.Controls.Add(timeLabel);
    textBoxCompose.Clear();
}
```

---

[image: chat window]

Comment: I tried the `Size(25, int.MaxValue)`. The long text seemed to get wrapped but the height value is the same as if I just typed "hi" which is `{Width=25, Height=23}`

Comment: I may have gotten thrown off by "I keep getting the output [...] **textBox.Size.Height: 0" being such a prominent part of the post...

Comment: This should be more of a fit for what you're trying to do.

Comment: [Clone](https://github.com/IVSoftware/chat-message-size.git) this sample.